# Create IF Formula in MS EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula which states if a value is between `X% and Y%`, then the text in the cell will read `Z`.

An example would be if a percentage in cell `C4` is between `1% and 39%`, then cell `D4` should read "*Unsatisfactory*". Similarly, between `40% and 49%` would be "*Of Concern*", etc.,

The values are:

> 0% = N/A 
> 1%-39% = Unsatisfactory
> 40%-49% = Of Concern
> 50%-64% = Satisfactory
> 65%-79% = Good
> 80%-89% = Very Good
> 90%-100% = Excellent

Comment: Hi taj, welcome to Stackoverflow. While we provided answers below, it is important that you include your attempts (formula you've written for this example) to solve your problem in your question otherwise, it will attract close votes like the 1 vote currently given to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `AND` together with `IF`. Something like below should work:

```
 =IF(C4>=90%,"Excellent",
  IF(AND(C4<90%,C4>=80%),"Very Good",
  IF(AND(C4<80%,C4>=65%),"Good",
  IF(AND(C4<65%,C4>=50%),"Satisfactory",
  IF(AND(C4<50%,C4>=40%),"Of Concern",
  IF(AND(C4<40%,C4>=1%),"Unsatisfactory",
  "N/A"))))))
```

The formula goes in `D4` as you've mentioned.

**Edit1:**
As mentioned by Andreas, if you really pay attention to the ordering, you can skip the `<` part. So above, can be simplified to:

```
 =IF(C4>=90%,"Excellent",
  IF(C4>=80%,"Very Good",
  IF(C4>=65%,"Good",
  IF(C4>=50%,"Satisfactory",
  IF(C4>=40%,"Of Concern",
  IF(C4>=1%,"Unsatisfactory",
  "N/A"))))))
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `less than` part. Because you start with the largest as soon as it will be true it will skip out and print the text.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to use a lookup table. This can use an array constant inside Lookup like this:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,1,40,50,65,80,90},{"N/A","Unsatisfactory","Of Concern","Satisfactory","Good","Very Good","Excellent"})
```

Or Vlookup with a table somwhere in your sheet like this

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,E$2:F$8,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: What if it's 55? The question is **between** not exact numbers

Comment: Satisfactory. Both Lookup and Vlookup (with 'TRUE') match anything less than or equal to the lookup value, so 55 matches with 50. It's equivalent to L42's second formula.

Comment: @Andreas I'll second Tom. Not unless you specify an exact match (for Vlookup).